# Random Password Generator C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop

The program should prompt the user for a 5 letter string. If the string is not 5 characters it displays an error message. If the password is 5 characters, using a while loop it generates the password in a new string variable by reversing the order of the characters in the string and subtracting 15 from each character to produce the password. Only iostream, iomanip, cmath, string libraries can be used.

The only problem I have with this question is constructing the while loop that reverses the original string into a new one and subtracts 15 from each character in the reversed string to construct the new password.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declaring/initializing variables
    string password, newPass;
    int index;


   // greeting message
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl
         << "     John Password Generator    " << endl
         << "-------------------------------" << endl;

    // asking user for input
    cout << "Please enter a 5 character word which will be used to generate                                                                                                              a       password: " << endl;
    getline(cin,password);

    // condition if password is less than or greather than 5 characters
    if (password.length() != 5)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, but that is not a 5 character string. Program will              terminate. \n\n"

        << "Thank you for using John Password Generator program.\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        password = string(password.rbegin(), password.rend());
        while (index < password.length())
    {

        index++;

    }


}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: So what code do you have so far? It's very hard to tell what you need help with without actually seeing any code? Consider [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I have posted what I have so far.

Comment: So you have successfully reversed the `string`, so why do you even need a `while` loop? It looks like that just freezes up the program, since `index = 0` and never changes.

Comment: We are required to implement the while loop for this question. Everything I have wrtten in the else statement is where I am having trouble.

Comment: You need to review your understanding of certain terminology. What you're trying to do is ***absolutely nothing like*** random password generation. You're just trying to mangle an input word with basic string manipulation.

Comment: It's an assignment question for intro to programming. It deals with basic ideas.

Comment: @BeGreat The basic idea is "string manipulation". Calling it a "random generator" is a misnomer, a fallacy, totally inaccurate. Even "password" is not strictly relevant because your question contains nothing specific to passwords. (Considering you're applying a simple cipher to to clear-text, 'encryption' would be a more relevant tag; though that would still be a stretch.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each element in `password`, and minus 15 from it:

```
index = 0;
password = string(password.rbegin(), password.rend());
while (index < password.length())
{
    // Minus 15 from each letter in password
    password[index] -= 15;
    // We've finished with this letter, so increment the index
    index++;
}
```

Of course, if you weren't limited by needing to use a `while` loop, you could use the standard library instead; specifically: [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to transform each letter in your `string`:

```
else
{
    // Start from the end of the string, and deduct 15 from the character and append it to the start of the string
    std::transform(password.rbegin(), password.rend(), password.begin(), [](unsigned char c){ return c - 15; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tas!